# Retorno nulo ao buscar a Chave Privada do certificado

Tags: c#, assinatura-digital

Estou precisando assinar uma string com um certificado digital.
Porém, ao passar pela linha que busca a chave privada, a variável `rsa` está ficando com o valor NULL, caindo dentro do `if` e fazendo com que o programa não continue sua execução.

Não consegui encontrar o motivo disso. Segue o código em C#:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

static public string assinar(X509Certificate2 cert, String sAssinatura) 
    {
        try
        {
            //recebe o certificado e a string a ser assinada
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            // Pega a chave privada do certificado digital
            if (cert.HasPrivateKey) // Até aqui OK
            {
                rsa = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider; // AQUI ESTÁ O PROBLEMA! "rsa" FICA null

                if (rsa == null)
                {
                    // ESTÁ CAINDO AQUI DENTRO!
                    Log.Gravar("RSA deu 'NULO' ao acessar a Chave Privada do Certificado!");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.Gravar("Não foi possível acessar Chave Privada do Certificado");
            }

            // ............... resto do código ............. //
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            return exc.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: O código parece ok. Qual certificado que você está usando?

Comment: Certificado comum, v3, instalado na máquina, com extensão pfx